# Combining multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I can't figure this out myself. Hope someone could help me.

I have three tables: `users`, `cards`, `referees` and `users_cards`

**Users:**

```
id  |   userName  |   referee_id
----------------------------
1   |   u1        |    1
2   |   u2        |    1
3   |   u3        |    2
```

**Referees:**

```
id  |   refName
--------------
1   |   ref1
2   |   ref2
```

**Cards:**

```
id  |   cardName
--------------
1   |   card1
2   |   card2
```

**Users_Cards:**

```
user_id  |   card_id  |   color   |   number
-------------------------------------------
1        |   1        |   red     |   123
1        |   2        |   yellow  |   312
2        |   2        |   yellow  |   523
3        |   1        |   red     |   344
```

The result I want to get is:

```
id   |   userName   |   refName   |   cards
1    |      u1      |    ref1     |   card1: red (123), card2: yellow (312)
2    |      u2      |    ref1     |   card2: yellow (523)
3    |      u3      |    ref2     |   card1: red (344)
```

And so on...

All I can get is multiple rows when user has more than a one card. So how can I combine them like this.

Thank you to anyone, who could help me!´

EDIT:

Currently I'm just using `LEFT JOIN`s

```
SELECT UserName, refName cardName, color, number,
FROM users
LEFT JOIN referees ON users.referee_id = referees.id
LEFT JOIN users_cards ON users.id = users_cards.user_id
LEFT JOIN cards ON dbo.users_cards.card_id = cards.id
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]?  The title mentions "SQL Server"...

Comment: post the query that you are currently using so we can get a better idea of how the data is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, UserName, refName,
 cards = (
    SELECT  
      STUFF(( 
           SELECT ', card' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cards.id) AS VARCHAR) 
                  +': '+ color + '(' + CAST(number AS VARCHAR) +')'
           FROM 
              users_cards
              LEFT JOIN cards ON dbo.users_cards.card_id = cards.id
           WHERE users.id = users_cards.user_id
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
  )
FROM users
LEFT JOIN referees ON users.refereeid = referees.id
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do the job. However, how could I also return `NULL` values?

Comment: Right now the subquery in the cards column returns NULL if there isn't any card association with the user. You could also change the inner join to a left join if you want to allow null referees.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no easy way to format the result of a table and append it to your result.
You can try doing a stored procedure with the following content:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    user_id int,
    CardString nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #userCards
(
    user_id int,
    CardsList nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @UserID int,
        @cardName nvarchar(50),
        @cardList nvarchar(250) 

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT user_id, cardName + ': ' + color + ' (' + number + ')'
FROM User_Cards AS UC
INNER JOIN Cards AS C ON C.card_id = UC.card_id

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP(1) @UserID = user_id FROM #temp

   SET @cardList = ''

   WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE user_id = @UserID)
   BEGIN
      SELECT TOP(1) @cardName = [CardString] FROM #temp WHERE user_id = @UserID
      IF @cardList <> ''
         SET @cardList = @cardList + ', '
      SET @cardList = @cardList + @cardName
   END

   INSERT INTO #userCards
   VALUES (user_id, @cardList)
END

SELECT users.id, users.userName, referees.refName, CardsList 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN referees ON users.referee_id = referees.id
LEFT JOIN #userCards ON #userCards.card_id = users.user_id

DROP TABLE #userCards
DROP TABLE #temp
```

This will return the content you wanted.
You can also define an aggregate function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx)